# MSVC building solution with msbuild

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, msbuild, visual-studio-2013

I have a problem. Few months ago i used msbuild to build my solution. All going fine but now i reinstall my Windows and change it to Windows 7 x64. And when i try to build my solution i got this message

> C:\Users\Alex\Desktop\Anti-Hack\trunk\AutoClicker\src\LordOfClicker\AutoClicker
>   .vcxproj(30,3): error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSB uild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V110\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props"
>   was not found. Confir m that the path in the  declaration is
>   correct, and that the file exist s on disk.

I try to build my solution with this CMD code:

```
C:\Users\Alex>C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe "C:\User
s\Alex\Desktop\Anti-Hack\trunk\Package.sln" /t:Clean /p:Configuration="Release [
Clicker]"
```

This problem appears only with solutions. When i try to build my project directly (vcxproj) - all going fine.

Currently i have only MSVC 2010 and 2013. What should i must to do? Install MSVC 2012? Or maybe someone can tell me easier way to fix it?

Thanks for advices!

Comment: i'm pretty sure there should not be a space in "MSB uild".

Comment: there is no spaces. Look at my CMD command

Comment: I mean the space in the eror mesage. ;-)

Comment: yep, i see it but this is not an error =). This error occurs because i havent msbuild for visual studio 2012

Comment: Perhaps you need to install the Windows SDK?